# how to pick latest files according to the latest uploaded date and process it in ADF

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have a folder in which every week new files will be dumped. i need to pick the latest files and process using ADF.
How to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get meta data activity to scan across all the files within the folder and filter out the file names based on the last processed date.
and than iteratively copy the files into destination and update the last processed date

Comment: thanks for your update, how to filter out the file names based on the last process date? it would be helpful if u share it across

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/136815/lates-file-extraction-azure-data-factory.html

This would contain diff approaches for the same